# How to get the width and height of jLabel when downsizing a window

Tags: java, events, height, width, jlabel

I have an event `formComponentResized` I want to get values when I upsize and downsize Jdialog an inside that a jLabel. when I upsize the window event is getting the new value of `jLabel1.getWidth()` and `jLabel1.getHeight()` but when I downsize it isn't getting the new value it is getting the old width and height of the `jLabel1`. Does anyone know the reason for this, or how to solve this problem.

**code:**

```
private void formComponentResized(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) 
{                                      
        BufferedImage resizedImage=ImageTools.resize(buffx,jLabel1.getWidth(),jLabel1.getHeight());       
        jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(resizedImage));
}
```

**resize method:**

```
public static BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage image, int width, int height) 
    {
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TRANSLUCENT);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) bi.createGraphics();
        g2d.addRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY));
        g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, null);
        g2d.dispose();
        return bi;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to scale the image based on the size of the label, then check out the [Stretch Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/) which does this for you automatically.

> Does anyone know the reason for this, or how to solve this problem.

Well, the code you posted is not complete so we don't know the context of how you are using the code. For example "formComponentResized" is not a Swing event. Did you add the component listener to the label or to the panel. You say it doesn't work when making the frame smaller, what about when the frame is made larger. Maybe the problem is the layout manager.

When you post a question post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem so we don't have to guess at all these questions.